# Using implicit operator overloading

Tags: c#, struct, casting, operator-overloading, operators

I created the following struct to keep track of all my network IDs I use for my game:

```
public struct NetworkId {
    private static int _availibleId = 1;

    private int _id;

    public static implicit operator int(NetworkId i) {
        if (i._id == 0) {
            i._id = _availibleId++;
        }

        return i._id;
    }
}
```

I initialize the ID at the moment someone tries to access it. But my problem now is, when I use the id like in the following example, the ID gets reassigned every time.

```
public class TestObject {
    private NetworkId _id;
    public NetworkId Id { get { return _id; } }

    public void Create {
        NetworkManager.SendPacket(new Packets.CreateObject(Id));
    }
}
```

I can't wrap my head around what is happening here. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please show the code where the field `private NetworkId _id;` is initialized to a value. Oh wait, `NetworkId` is struct so it gets copied over and over again. Mutable structs are evil you know.

Comment: You are not showing enough code of how `NetwordId` is used to effectively answer the question.

Comment: This is a terrible idea and you should not do this.  A conversion should not have a side effect! Your code says "every time I convert this ID to an integer, create a different integer".  What are you *really* trying to do here?

Comment: It looks like you have thoroughly conflated two completely different things: "make a new unique identifier" and "convert that identifier to an integer".

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be a struct?  With class semantics do this:

```
public class NetworkId
{
    private static int _availibleId = 1;
    public int Id { get; } = _availibleId++;

    public static implicit operator int(NetworkId i)
    {
        return i.Id;
    }
}

void Test() {
    int A = new NetworkId();  //A=1
    int B = new NetworkId();  //B=2
}
```

Comment: Not necessarily, but because it represents only a single value it seemed more fitting to be a struct. In the effort of getting it to work, I made it a class now, but I still want to understand why my previous approach wasn't working.